# objective C: no @interface for NSCalander declares the select timeIntervalSince

Tags: objective-c

just started to learn some objective-C and I am writing a piece of code to find how many seconds I have been alive:

```
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
                      [comps setYear:1990];
                      [comps setMonth:2];
                      [comps setDay:12];
                      [comps setHour:1];
                      [comps setMinute:1];
                      [comps setSecond:0];

                               NSCalendar *g = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
                               NSDate *dateOfBirth = [g dateFromComponents:comps];

                     double d = [g timeIntervalSinceDate:dateOfBirth]; // getting error "no visible @interface for NSCalander declares the select timeIntervalSince"

                     NSLog(@"i have been alive for %d", d);
```

There are some other questions with about this error but I cant seem to use any of the answers on my code.

Any help would be great, cheers!

Comment: why the down votes guys? So I can improve my questions in the future. I feel I researched on this site adequately. Like I said I am completely new to this language, and not very experienced in general so may be a bit of a silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["`timeIntervalSinceDate:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceDate%3a) is a method on NSDate, not NSCalendar.

If you change your code to:

```
NSTimeInterval d = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: dateOfBirth];
```

you may have happier results (my one line of code should give you the time interval between the date/time right now and the date of birth).

Comment: Great answer, very interesting too. +1 :D

Comment: He needs %f in the NSLog as well.